# Misunderstanding of the definition of the tensor product of algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

In Atiyah it says that if B,C are A-algebras with $$ f:A\to B~ ~and~~ g:A\to C$$ then their tensor product is D and a ring homomorphism $$h:A\to D~~~ with ~~a\mapsto f(a)\otimes g(a)$$ I don't understand how this map is additive. I can see that it's multiplicative, but I'm left with:
$$f(a_1)\otimes g(a_1)+f(a_2)\otimes g(a_2)=f(a_1)\otimes g(a_1)+f(a_1)\otimes g(a_2)+f(a_2)\otimes g(a_1)+f(a_2)\otimes g(a_2)\Rightarrow2a_1a_2(1\otimes1)=0$$

Comment: You are right, this is not the correct description of the tensor product. $h$ can be given by *either* $a \mapsto f(a) \otimes 1$ or $a \mapsto 1 \otimes g(a)$, the construction of the tensor product makes these the same.